# Caddy: How to serve static files from Django

Tags: python, django, caddy, caddyfile

It's my first experience with Caddy and I'm having difficulties configuring it properly concerning static files.

I'm using an Ubuntu server and I'm running Caddy and Django+Gunicorn as Docker containers.

It works perfectly well except that it gives a 404 on static files such as CSS and JS files.

I've collected all static files to their corresponding directories in /home/myusername/static and have the following Caddyfile:

```
mydomain.com {
  encode gzip
  
  handle_path /static/* {
        root * "/home/myusername/static/"
        file_server
    }

  handle_path /media/* {
        root * "/home/myusername/media/"
        file_server
    }

  reverse_proxy django-gunicorn-container-name:8000
}
```

What should I do to make Caddy serve static files correctly?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using the following Dockerfile and Docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /pairs_trade_front_end_docker 
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nohup python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput & nohup python3 manage.py migrate & gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 setup.wsgi:application"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  database:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ~/postgres-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
       stats-trade-network:
         aliases:
           - postgresForStatsTrade
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5 
    restart: unless-stopped
           
  webserver:
    image: 'antoniorcampos/pairs-trade:0.9'
    container_name: stats-trade-web-server
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ~/static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
       stats-trade-network:
         aliases:
           - webserverForStatsTrade
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped

  caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
    networks:
       stats-trade-network:
         aliases:
           - caddyForStatsTrade
    depends_on:
      webserver:
        condition: service_started
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  stats-trade-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And then I copy the static files to /home/myusername/static using a basic linux command line `cp -r ...`. I do it using myusername.

Comment: please post the dockerfile (or docker-compose.yaml) of your caddy container. caddy, running inside the container, must have access to that static folder

Comment: @baumschubser, thanks for replying. I've added the files to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem: You mount the `static` folder as volume into your `stats-trade-container`, so that application can access `static`.
However, you do not mount the `static` folder into the Caddy container. Change the Caddy section of your docker-compose.yml like so (notice the second line in the volumes part):

```
caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - ~/static:/www/html
    networks:
       stats-trade-network:
         aliases:
           - caddyForStatsTrade
    depends_on:
      webserver:
        condition: service_started
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Now Caddy can access the static files and sees them in the folder /www/html. Next, change the Caddyfile to point Caddy to that folder instead of /home/username….

```
handle_path /static/* {
    root * /www/html
    file_server
}
```

These changes should make it work.

P.S.: From the Caddyfile, it looks like you want to do something similar for the "media" folder. You can do it in a similar way, just point it to a different location than /www/html (e.g. /media).

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you!